# What software do I need to convert a pdf to text that can then be processed using regex to extract specific pieces of data?

Tags: pdf, database, automation, data-analysis, regex

I have a bunch of pdf files/forms that are all in a standardized format.  They contain information such version history, author, who signed the document, and what documents it references.  I need to extract that information to feed into a database containing information about the documents.  I am pretty sure I could do this using a regular expression(s),but I am not entirely sure how to go about it.  I would like to automate the process also, so that when new documents are created, they are added to the system, and also the system looks at all the documents on a web page and extracts the information.

Comment: On Linux you can use `exiftool` to extract `.pdf` metadata and parse its output using regular expressions. For example, to find `Creator` of a given `.pdf`: `exiftool doc.pdf | grep "^Creator" | perl -pe 's,^Creator.+: (.*)$,\1,'`. To find an author: `exiftool doc.pdf | grep "^Author" | perl -pe 's,^Author.+: (.*)$,\1,'`

Comment: However, some of the information about the document that I need to extract will not be in the normal metadata.  There will be a section of text in the document itself, saying authorized by:  "" or References:  "".  It needs to extract the actual text from the document and extract specific text from that.

Comment: It's possible to convert `.pdf` document to a text file. After doing that it should be possible to extract a piece of text depending on how regular will it be using regular expcessions. You did not specify what OS you are using but on `*nix` it's possible to automate this using `pdftotext` command line tool and a combination of `grep/sed/cut/awk/perl`

Comment: what would the syntax for that pdftotext command look like when used?

Comment: Have you every used Linux command line? Use it just it says in `man pdftotext`: `pdftotext [options] [PDF-file [text-file]]`. It also says that `Pdftotext  reads  the  PDF file, PDF-file, and writes a text file, text-file.  If text-file is not specified, pdftotext converts file.pdf to file.txt.  If text-file is Â´-', the text is sent to stdout.`. So, for example: `pdftotext <doc>.pdf` will produce `<doc>.txt` in the same directory.

Comment: I have used linux command line before, and used bash, awk, and sed.  A little bit rusty, but I still remember the basics.  Was just asking what arguments were passed and how.

Comment: You could as well look it up in `pdftotext` manpage and learn it much faster. To download/upload documents from/to a web server you can use `scp` if `SSH` access is enabled or `lftp`, extract metadata locally and push it to a web server. You will need to have a list of documents you already processed. Alternatively, you don't even need to download `.pdf` from the web server because you can process it directly on the web server or mount a remote directory with `sshfs`.

Comment: You can trigger the operation of extracting metadata every time a new `.pdf` is added using `inotify` mechanism or some kind of web server callback or execute it regularly using a `crontab` job. I am still not sure whether you prefer `*nix` or Windows. If you prefer the latter, I can't help you because I don't use it. **BTW**: it's already too much for a comment so if you like this I will convert it to an answer and you may accept it.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk that would be good.  I was wondering why you hadn't actually.

Comment: Oh, and although I use windows more for general use, this is on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to convert `.pdf` document to a text file. After doing that it should be possible to extract a piece of text depending on how regular will it be using regular expressions. You did not specify what OS you are using but on `*nix` it's possible to automate this using `pdftotext` command line tool and a combination of `grep/sed/cut/awk/perl`.

To download/upload documents from/to a web server you can use `scp` if `SSH` access is enabled or `lftp`, extract metadata locally and push it to a web server. You will need to have a list of documents you already processed. Alternatively, you don't even need to download `.pdf` from the web server because you can process it directly on the web server or mount a remote directory with `sshfs`. You can trigger the operation of extracting metadata every time a new `.pdf` is added using `inotify` mechanism or some kind of web server callback or execute it regularly using a `crontab` job.

I am still not sure whether you prefer `*nix` or `Windows`. If you prefer the latter, I can't help you because I don't use it.